# Pythonanywhere hourly task send email once if there is a booking

Tags: python, smtp

I have the code below, basically it sends an email if there is a new booking. It runs hourly on pyhtonanywhere tasks, so it checks if there is a new order every hour. The code is fine but I cannot come up with a solution to stop it sending the email if it already found the order and start again the following day.

Normally there is only one order a day. So if it finds a new order it should send the email and restart checking the following day.

any idea?

```
import urllib
import sys
import json
import requests
import smtplib

new_order=False

#email log in variables
gmail_user = 'info@XXXXX.com'
gmail_password = 'XXXXXXXX'

# Create Email
mail_from = "info@XXXXX.com"
mail_to = 'XXXXX@mtlcz.com'

mail_subject = 'New booking from XXXXXXX'
#mail_message_body = mytext



base_url = 'https://XXX.XXXXX.co.uk/api/3.0/booking?created_date=TODAY'
client_id='XXXXXX'
client_secret='XXXXXX'

#return a json oject with the bookings data
response = requests.get(base_url,auth=(client_id, client_secret))
mycustomer=response.json()


#checks if there is a booking for the day
if mycustomer['request']['records']==0:
  print ('no  bookings for this date')


#if there is a booking continue
if  mycustomer['request']['records']>0:

  #gets the keys of the booking and turns into booking ids
  for key in mycustomer['booking/index'].keys():
      my_booking_id = key
#checks if the tours are bookings delight
  if "foodie's delight tour" in mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['summary']:
#extracts the data of the bookings
    my_customer_email =mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['customer_email']
    my_customer_name=mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['customer_name']
    my_payment=mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['status_id']
    tour_booked=mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['summary']
    date_booking=mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['date_desc']
    booking_id=mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['booking_id']

    # get more info from order ###add this part
    booking_order_code =mycustomer['booking/index'][my_booking_id]['code']
    base_url = https://XXXXX.XXXXX.co.uk/api/3.0/booking/'+booking_order_code
    response3 = requests.get(base_url,auth=(client_id, client_secret))
    mycustomer3=response3.json()
    deposit=mycustomer3['booking']['deposit_due']
    quantity=mycustomer3['booking']['items']['1']['qty']


    mytext='''

    Hello,

    there is a new booking for XXXXX XXXXX, here some details:

    the booking ID is: '''+ str(booking_id) + '''
    The date of event  is:  ''' + date_booking + '''
    The customer email is:  ''' + my_customer_email +'''
    The customer name is:  '''   +my_customer_name +'''
    This cumstomer booked : ''' + tour_booked +'''
    The status of the payment is ''' + my_payment +'''
    Deposit owned is '''+deposit+'''
    People booked on activity '''+quantity+'''


    A more detailed email will follow
    Unless indicated above the tours will leave from 

    '''





#CREATES AND SEND THE EMAIL

try:
   mail_message_body = mytext
   mail_message = '''\
   From: %s
   To: %s
   Subject: %s
   %s
   ''' % (mail_from, mail_to, mail_subject, mail_message_body)
   server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.XXXXXXX.com', 465)
   server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
   server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)
   server.close()
   print ('email has been sent')
   print (mail_message_body)
   booking_sent=True

except:
    print ('there are no booking today')
```

Answer (score 0):

Store somewhere (database, a json file or whatever) that you have sent the email and then check that store when you want to send the email and only send it if you have not already done so.